# Ruby on Rails: Polymorphic Association Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, model-associations

I am contributing one of the ruby on rails application over GitHub where I faced the following scenario:

I am having following models which I want to convert to make polymorphic:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :project
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, -> { order('created_at DESC') }, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Application < Rails::Application
end
```

I made following changes to make it polymorphic:

Perform database change to removed `team_id`, `project_id`, `application_id` and `user_id` and added `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` to `comments` table.

Modifications in models as described within rails guides.:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, -> { order('created_at DESC') }, dependent: :destroy
end
```

While I use it with default scope, It doesn't allow me to use with default scope and gives error with below line:

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, -> { order('created_at DESC') }, dependent: :destroy
```

I am confused to change in following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Should I need following changes in `User` and `Application` model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does your user/application object needs comments. If yes then add it

Comment: Have you tried `has_many :comments, :through => :commentable` ?

Answer (score 0):

if your user/application object needs comments then add

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

else create belongs_to/has_many relationship not polymorphic
Eg.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```